# minimax: what happens if min plays not optimal

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

the description of the minimax algo says, that both player have to play optimal, so that the algorithm is optimal. Intuitively it is understandable. But colud anyone concretise, or proof what happens if min plays not optimal?

thx

Comment: Then Max has a better chance of winning.

Comment: For clarification, if the min does not play optimally, this means that you are **not** implementing the minimax algorithm, but a flawed version.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of "optimal" is that you play so as to minimize the "score" (or whatever you measure) of your opponent's optimal answer, which is defined by the play that minimizes the score of your optimal answer and so forth.

Thus, by definition, if you don't play optimal, your opponent has at least one path that will give him a higher score than his best score if you played optimal.

One way to find out what is optimal is to brute force the entire game tree. For less than trivial problems you can use alpha-beta search, which guarantees optimum without needing to search the entire tree. If you tree is still too complex, you need a heuristic that estimates what the score of a "position" is and halts at a certain depth.

Was that understandable?

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems with that precise question.

When you think about it for a bit you will get the idea that the minimax graph contains ALL possible games including the bad games.  So if a player plays a sub optimal game then that game is part of the tree - but has been discarded in favor of a better game.

Its similar to alpha beta. I was getting stuck on what happens if I sacrifice some pieces intentionally to create space and then make a winning move through the gap.  ie there is a better move further down the tree.

With alpha beta - lets say a sequence of losing moves followed by a killer move is in fact in the tree - but in that case the alpha and beta act as a window filter "a< x < b" and would have discarded it if YOU had a better game.  You can see it in alpha beta if you imagine putting a +/- infinity into a pruned branch to see what happens.

In any case both algorithms recalculate every move so that if a player plays a sub optimal game them that will open up branches of the graph that are better for the opponent.

rinse repeat.

Comment: If both play in an optimal way does this imply that the starting player has an advantage in such games?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a MIN node whose children are terminal nodes. If MIN plays suboptimally, then the value of the node is greater than or equal to the value it would have if MIN played optimally. Hence, the value of the MAX node that is the MIN node’s parent can only be increased. This argument can be extended by a simple induction all the way to the root. If the suboptimal play by MIN is predictable, then one can do better than a minimax strategy. For example, if MIN always falls for a certain kind of trap and loses, then setting the trap guarantees a win even if there is actually a devastating response for MIN.

Source: https://www.studocu.com/en-us/document/university-of-oregon/introduction-to-artificial-intelligence/assignments/solution-2-past-exam-questions-on-computer-information-system/1052571/view